# Formatting issue with <table> in Magento

Tags: css, magento, html-table

I've got a huge issue with inserting tables into the description page of Magento.

Here is a product I've been testing it on.

http://www.buffalonutrition.co.uk/gaspari-myofusion-probiotic-2-2kg.html

For some reason the table is place all the way down to the bottom, and a ton of `<br>` tags are inserted.

I have also "Completely Disabled" WYSIWYG Editing in the Settings/Configuration/Content Management side.

Anyone got any ideas on this? As I would really like to have each product showing product nutritional values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's relating to this problem here;

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/29526/#t96842

The nl2br function is being applied to carriage returns in your content. Do you have the WYSIWYG editor disabled?  If not then I would disable it (System -> Configuration -> General -> Content Management) and enter the html for your table straight into the description.

Comment: Yes, I've completely disabled WYSIWYG yet I still have the problem.

Comment: Okay I've deleted nl2br, but I've been thinking. It would be better if I created a new attribute field. And added that to the page.